# Caught set but unused parameters with clang

Tags: c++, c, clang

Is there a way I could catch set but unused variables using clang, something similar to gcc's `Werror=unused-but-set-parameter`?
I set `-Wunused` but clang doesn't catch set but unused parameters.

Comment: You have looked ***[here](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html)***?

Comment: I can't any relevant option, but gcc catches unused-but-set-parameters when -Wunused is set.

Comment: did you use it following `-Wextra`? (see below for more details, and some additional links that discuss ways to use GCC compatible settings within CLANG.)

Comment: I'd like to re-awaken this issue.  I cannot find any flags that will disable these warnings in Xcode 10: `"Value stored to 'sql' is never read"`  The flag "-Wunused-variable" is not the one because the variable is used but I set it several times with different values before is it used.  (I do this intentionally and I have reasons.  I want to suppress the warning.)  I can't find this particular warning in the Clang documentation.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you have tried more than what you have listed, but here is more information on CLANG *unused* options, using its GCC compatibility:

***First***, here is what the documentation suggests:

```
-Wextra  -Wunused-but-set-parameter
```

***The following is background reference information:***

From ***[HERE](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2011/09/20/disabling-clang-compiler-warnings.html)***:

*If you are using the LLVM-GCC or Apple LLVM Compiler build option there are a large number of possible compiler warnings that you can enable/disable. The Clang front end also supports the GCC diagnostic warnings (see http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html) for backwards compatibility.*

Following the referenced link in that quote lists several *unused* options from the GCC family of warnings:

-Wall
    *This enables all the warnings about constructions that some users consider questionable, and that are easy to avoid (or modify to prevent the warning), even in conjunction with macros. This also enables some language-specific warnings described in C++ Dialect Options and Objective-C and Objective-C++ Dialect Options.*

```
    -Wall turns on the following warning flags:   
(there are many more, just listing 'unused')

              ...  

              -Wunused-function  
              -Wunused-label     
              -Wunused-value     
              -Wunused-variable  
              ...
```

And finally, just below the last block:

```
-Wextra
    This enables some extra warning flags that are not enabled by -Wall.   
    (This option used to be called -W. The older name is still supported, but the newer name is more descriptive.)  
(again, there are more, just listing _unused variety)  

              -Wunused-parameter (only with -Wunused or -Wall) 
              -Wunused-but-set-parameter (only with -Wunused or -Wall)
```

Comment: I have done all what you have said, well I had already done it because what I am basically trying to do is port an already existing large code-base to clang.It happens that errors that I was previously catching with gcc can no longer be caught with clang.I asked clang developers, they say there is no such a warning yet.Thanks though

Answer (score 1):

There is an equivalent warning generated by [clang-tidy](http://clang.llvm.org/extra/clang-tidy/), integrated from [clang-analyzer](https://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/available_checks.html#deadcode_checkers):

```
note: Value stored to 'tmp' is never read
warning: Value stored to 'tmp' is never read [clang-analyzer-deadcode.DeadStores]
```

It looks like LLVM chose to implement some of the GCC warnings as separate tools.

Comment: It seems these tools are not included in macOS default compiler? I'm checking using "Apple LLVM version 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.37)". Anyway, if you are right, then this should be an accepted answer, for now.

Answer (score -1):

In this [website](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/DiagnosticsReference.html), if you search for 'unused' you can find some flags that you could use. And I think [this](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/DiagnosticsReference.html#wunused-variable) one is your flag:

```
clang -Wunused-variable test.c
```

Comment: I don't think so? My case activates the screaming of `-Wunused-but-set-variable` of GCC 4.8.5 while it does not activate the screaming of `-Wunused-variable` of Apple LLVM version 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.37).